# CSS & Jquery top header slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slide

I want create a top panel slider same like this [website](https://corp.onlinesbi.com/khata/login.htm) when I view that website source I see everything , since I copy the particular codes which help to create this but I have two issues.

**Screenshot Image**

[image: Screenshot Image]

1. I  am not able to make my code slidable when I hit the option.
2. I am unable to crop that slide menu image button from this [image](https://corp.onlinesbi.com/personal/images/sprite_a.png).

Hii wanna please help me, I am really in trouble , how to I make slidable or crop menu image from this [image](https://corp.onlinesbi.com/personal/images/sprite_a.png).

To view source code of that original website is here and website is [here](https://corp.onlinesbi.com/khata/login.htm).

**My code is:**

```css
#netbanking_branches {
  margin: 0 0px 0 10px;
}

.netbanking_button {
  background-position: -58px -643px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 200px;
}

#netbanking_branches,
.netbanking_button {
  float: left;
}

.netbanking_button,
.netbanking_button_up {
  background-image: url("https://corp.onlinesbi.com/personal/images/sprite_a.png") ! important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#netbanking_popup {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #cbcbcb;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: #d9d9d9 url("https://corp.onlinesbi.com/personal/images/netbanking_repeat.png" repeat-x;
  width: 100%;
}

#netbanking_content {
  background: url("https://corp.onlinesbi.com/personal/images/netbanking_img.png") no-repeat left top;
  height: 123px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 255px;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#netbanking_content_heading {
  color: #0197c0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#netbanking_popup,
.product_content {
  display: none;
}

#netbanking_popup {
  position: absolute;
}

#netbanking_content_heading {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header core info -->
<div id="netbanking_branches" class="netbanking_branches">
  <a href="" class="netbanking_button" title="Netbanking Branches" tabindex="4">&nbsp;</a>
  <div id="netbanking_popup">
    <div id="netbanking_content">
      <div id="netbanking_content_heading">
        <p>contant</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Header core info Ends-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to do some changes:

1. You need to add js code to handle the `click` event on the button.
2. I changed the css and the html a bit so it will fit to the behaviour you want.
3. I'm using css3 transition to create the "slide" effect. For more info, read this [post](https://davidwalsh.name/css-slide)
4. The strange line in the left of the logo you marked is not coming from the image but from the link (`a` tag). You put there a space character and the `a` tag has `text-decoration: underline` by default so the line draw by this rule.

```js
const netbankingPopup = document.querySelector('#netbanking_popup');
document.querySelector('.netbanking_button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  netbankingPopup.classList.toggle('visible');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

#netbanking_branches {
  text-align: center;
}

.netbanking_button {
  background-position: -58px -643px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 200px;
}

.netbanking_button {
  display: inline-block;
}

.netbanking_button,
.netbanking_button_up {
  background-image: url("https://corp.onlinesbi.com/personal/images/sprite_a.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#netbanking_popup {
  background: #d9d9d9 url("https://corp.onlinesbi.com/personal/images/netbanking_repeat.png") repeat-x;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .3s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
}

#netbanking_popup.visible {
  max-height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #cbcbcb;
}

#netbanking_popup.visible + .netbanking_button {
  background-position: -58px -590px;
}

#netbanking_content {
  background: url("https://corp.onlinesbi.com/personal/images/netbanking_img.png") no-repeat left top;
  height: 123px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 255px;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#netbanking_content_heading {
  color: #0197c0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.product_content {
  display: none;
}

#netbanking_content_heading {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header core info -->
<div id="netbanking_branches" class="netbanking_branches">
  <div id="netbanking_popup">
    <div id="netbanking_content">
      <div id="netbanking_content_heading">
        <p>contant</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="netbanking_button" title="Netbanking Branches" tabindex="4"></a>
</div>
<!-- Header core info Ends-->
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer you done same as I want but there 2 issue still , actually the `contant -> paragraph` areas  I want 100% and want to make error indicator when slider is down arrow show up and when top arrow shows down.

Comment: Just updated my answer. Pay attention to the css part, it's important to understand how it works (the difference between `float` and `display: inline-block` for example)

Comment: How I delete the white space of right and left side of slider and make fix set in window as top.?

Comment: I updated my answer. Just remove the `margin` from `#netbanking_branches` and set `body` `margin` to `0` (it's `5px` by default)

Comment: How to I thank you, you are really genius and eligible to take vote up. But button not align in center and hiw I delete un-usefull image from this image please view`https://corp.onlinesbi.com/personal/images/sprite_a.png`

Comment: My pleasure :) Just updated my answer. 
Small note, if I may, for a feature web developer, I strongly recommend to try to do things by yourself (such as align items to center). I'm sure you already do this, but quick search like "how to align content to center in css" will answer you a good question. Sure you understand :) About the image, if it yours just edit it and update the styles (`background-position`) of the relevant elements. You can use this great tool: http://www.spritecow.com/

Comment: I visite tour spritecow.com but not understand how I script that two `up and down` image from all list images and add in Css. Please this paste help me..To I always remember you.

Comment: You need to remove the part by yourself (using photoshop or something). This tool just helps you to find the coords in your image.

Comment: Thank u for your help

Comment: But what I will add two images when I will separate this two image. Let supposed `image1 for top` and `image 2 for down`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment but for now, you have 2 images in the sprite. You can see in my demo that the images are replacing when you click on the link.

Comment: Yes you are right but this image is in list and when I remove it via Photoshop then it will separate and then I can only able to add anyone image instead `
  background-image: url("https://corp.onlinesbi.com/personal/images/sprite_a.png`

Comment: Sorry for disturb you again but please help me how I add your code on this website `shivkumar.in.net` body is not slid down with panel slider and not shows in proper way. Please help last

Comment: It's all good. I'm in your favour. You just need to change the `class`es and `id`s so it will match the example. For example, replace `heardr_popbutton` with `netbanking_button` and so on.

Comment: Could you copy my website page source code and then correct it I will very obliged to you.`shivkumar.in.net`

Comment: Sorry, but I have no time for this.. Also, it's a good practice for you..

Comment: I do but it not happened from my end. There is nothing for do more you can please help , please try

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery with onclick event on each of your elements to slide down and show them.

do not forget to import jQuery library :7

**Use this:**

```
    <div id="netbanking_branches" class="netbanking_branches">
      <a href="" class="netbanking_button" id="netbanking_button" title="Netbanking Branches" tabindex="4"></a>
      <div id="netbanking_popup">
        <div id="netbanking_content">
          <div id="netbanking_content_heading">
            <p>contant</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div id="content">
     content in your upper slider
    <div id="netbanking_button">close</div>
   </div>
    <script>
      jQuery('#netbanking_button').on('click',function(){
         $('#content').slideDown();
      });
      jQuery('#netbanking_button_close').on('click',function(){
         $('#content').slideUp();
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Problem in your jquery